# Using MongoDB as message queue for Celery

Tags: django, mongodb, message-queue, rabbitmq, celery

I'm trying to use MongoDB as the message queue for Celery (in a Django app). The current development version of Celery (2.2.0rc2) is supposed to let you do this, but I can't seem to get any workers to pick up tasks I'm creating.

Versions:
celery v2.2.0rc3
mongodb 1.6.5
pymongo 1.9
django-celery 2.2.0rc2

In my settings, I have:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "mongodb"
CELERY_MONGODB_BACKEND_SETTINGS = {
    # Shouldn't need these - defaults are correct.
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 27017,
    "database": "celery",
    "taskmeta_collection": "messages",
}

BROKER_BACKEND = 'mongodb'
BROKER_HOST = "localhost"
BROKER_PORT = 27017
BROKER_USER = ""
BROKER_PASSWORD = ""
BROKER_VHOST = ""

import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

I've created a test tasks.py file as follows:

```
from celery.decorators import task

@task()
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

If I fire up celeryd in the background, it appears to start normally. I then open a python shell and run the following:

```
>>> from myapp.tasks import add
>>> result = add.delay(5,5)
>>> result
<AsyncResult: 7174368d-288b-4abe-a6d7-aeba987fa886>
>>> result.ready()
False
```

Problem is that no workers ever pick up the tasks. Am I missing a setting or something? How do I point celery to the message queue?

Comment: Is the app in installed apps? What is celery returning in its logs if anything? One common reason that .ready() will return False when it really shouldn't is because the tasks is not recognized, Celery will say something like "Unknown task ignored: .... "

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am having the same issue

Comment: I didn't, unfortunately.

Comment: what happens when you call "result.get()" (and you can also check if there is an exception thrown by worker from "result.result"

Answer (score 2):

We had this same issue.  While the doc says all tasks should be registered in Celery by calling

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

it wasn't working properly.  So, we still used the

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('YOUR_APP.tasks',)
```

setting in settings.py. Also, make sure you restart Celery if you add a new task because Celery has to register the tasks when it first starts.

[Django, Celerybeat and Celery with MongoDB as the Broker](http://blog.troygrosfield.com/2011/11/22/django-celerybeat-and-celery-with-mongodb-as-the-broker/)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Kombu work only with mongo 1.3+ because it need the functionality findandmodify.
If you are on ubuntu the last version in repository is the 1.2, than doesn't work.

Maybe you have also to set
BROKER_VHOST = "dbname"

Keep me posted if it works

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to add this to your settings, or the workers can't find the task and will fail silently.

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("namespace", )
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but when I upgraded to celery 2.3.3 everything worked like a charm.